# Overriding typescript interface property

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to override an interface to force a property on the interface to be an enum. This is something I'd expect to be trivial, but is seemingly impossible.

All I want to do is have the `customCode` property on `IBaseErrorOptions` be an enum `CustomErrorCode`. Is this possible or am I just going down a rabbit hole here?

In ErrorTypes.d.ts

```
export interface IBaseErrorOptions {
    customCode?: string | number | null;
}
export declare class BaseError  {
    constructor(message: string, options: IBaseErrorOptions);
}
```

In a file.ts

```
enum CustomErrorCode {
  Missing = 'missing',
}
interface IMyBaseErrorOptions {
  customCode: CustomErrorCode;
}

declare class MyBaseError {
  constructor(message: string, options: IMyBaseErrorOptions);
}




declare module 'ErrorTypes' {
  /**
    All declarations of 'customCode' must have identical modifiers.ts(2687)
  
    Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'customCode' must be of type 'string | number | null | undefined', but here has type 'CustomErrorCode'.ts(2717)
  */
  interface IBaseErrorOptions {
    customCode: CustomErrorCode;
  }

  /**
    ErrorTypes.d.ts 'BaseError' was also declared here.
  */

  class BaseError extends MyBaseError {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to achieve isn't possible in TypeScript. You can't assign new types to existing properties in this Module Augmentation way.

The best option you have is probably to create a new type based on the one you have and override it's type, something like:

```
// Create a new type alias with the correct type for 'customCode'
export type NewIBaseErrorOptions = Omit<IBaseErrorOptions, 'customCode'> & { customCode: CustomErrorCode };
```